# Why doesn't Ace editor apply CSS classes to a div?

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I'm trying out the tutorial for Ace given [here](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding). If this is my HTML/CSS:

```
.codeElement {
    font-family: ..;
    font-size: ..;
}

<div id="editor" class="codeElement">..code..</div>
```

Then the `font-family` and `font-size` settings are ignored. However, when I write this:

```
#editor {
    font-family: ..;
    font-size: ..;
}

<div id="editor" class="codeElement">..code..</div>
```

It works. Why does this happen/how can I work around it?

Comment: Have you inspected the element in your brower's dev console? It's possible that the class is being overridden by a more specific ruleset.

Comment: CSS rules have priority - if you have another style with higher priority than the class selector, it will override it. `#id`s, though, have the highest priority and so when you use `#editor` it overrides all other rules.

Answer (score 0):

Ace adds a [css rule](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/css/editor.css#L4) `.ace_editor { font: ... }` which can override your rule if it is added after your stylesheet.

Css rule for id has higher specificity, and always takes over the rule added by ace.

As a workaround you can use `!important` or a more specific selector like `.codeElement.ace_editor`